# XSLT get context node inside nested conditions

Tags: xslt, xpath

Actually I don't have really a question, I just want a conformation for my assumption.
I guess it is not possible to get the node from the start of the select `./attribute` inside the nested conditions at the place where  I have written `here you need the current attribute from the start of select`, because I am already in the context of the variable `$oldBaseline`.
Or is there any way? Of course I can store this node inside a variable but this is always possible...

```
    <xsl:variable name="changedMonitorSettings" 
        select="./attribute[($oldBaseline/module/object/object[attribute[@name='Object Text']=$currentObject/attribute[@name='Object Text']]
            /attribute[@name = "here you need the current attribute from the start of select"/@name]) !=.]"/>
```

I need to add some more details:
The `object` node looks like this. There are a lot of `attribute` nodes. I want to compare every `attribute` from one xml with the same named `attribute` of another xml.

```
        <object>
            <attribute name="CM_ABS">CM_NORMAL</attribute>
            <attribute name="CM_AVH">CM_AVH_INHIBIT</attribute>
            <attribute name="CM_BCM">CM_BCM_NORMAL</attribute>
            <attribute name="CM_BHM">CM_BHM_NORMAL</attribute>
            <attribute name="CM_BRAKE_AC">CM_BRAKE_AC_NORMAL</attribute>
            <attribute name="CM_CC">CM_CC_NORMAL</attribute>
            <attribute name="CM_EDTR">CM_EDTR_NORMAL</attribute>
            <attribute name="CM_EYT">CM_EYT_NORMAL</attribute>
```

Therfore I need during the xslt processing for every `attribute`, at the mentioned place inside the predicate, the `attribute` which is currently under investigation during this processing step. Because I need to check if the `attribute` from the `oldBaseline` has the same name like the `attribute` which is currently used in the processing step. I think the `current()` function will not work, because it just returns the `object` node, thus `current()/attribute` just returns the first `attribute` of the `object` node.
Thus I need to correct me, that I am already in the context of `$oldBaseline` is acutally not the point, I have faced this issue some months ago...

So the question is now:
It is possible to get the `attribute` node which is currently under investigation in the current processing step?

Answer (score 0):

XPath 3 has a `let` expression to bind variables (e.g. `./attribute[let $a := . return ($oldBaseline/module/object/object[attribute[@name='Object Text']=$currentObject/attribute[@name='Object Text']]/attribute[@name = $a/@name]) !=.]` if I manage to handle that long expression, I have not tested whether there are parenthesis needed to structure it as intended).

In XPath 2 it might be possible to exploit the `for .. return` instead of let e.g. `./attribute[for $a in . return ($oldBaseline/module/object/object[attribute[@name='Object Text']=$currentObject/attribute[@name='Object Text']]/attribute[@name = $a/@name]) !=.]`.

A cross-reference/comparison based on an attribute or element value might also suggest that a key declared with `xsl:key` and the use of the `key` function could help simplify the expression and improve the lookup performance.